# When should "black and white" use hyphens?

Tags: adjectives

I would like to know what the rule is to hyphen "black and white". In example 1, I am hyphening it because it goes before a noun, whereas, in example 2, I am not hyphening it because there is no noun after it. Am I doing it correctly? What is the rule here?

> 1. Wars are presented in **black-and-white** terms by the contenders.

> 2. Good journalists know that the truth is not **black and white**.

Comment: The noun is "a hyphen", but the verb is "to hyphen**ate**".

Answer (score 1):

Phrases that modify nouns are hyphenated if they are used as an *attributive adjective*, that's to say, *before the noun they're modifying*, like in your first example.

If the phrase is used as a *predicate adjective*, that's to say, after the main verb like in your second example, then the phrase is not hyphenated.

This rule is often described as, "hyphenate when it's an adjective", but this is not accurate since adjectives in the predicate are also adjectives, and they're not hyphenated.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, that is correct.  Phrases are hyphenated when they are used to modify a noun (i.e. when they are used like an adjective).  This turns the phrase into a single "item" that modifies the noun, and helps make it clear that those words are being used together *as a phrase* to modify the noun.

For example, in your first sentence we know from your hyphens that you are not talking about some "terms that are black" and some "terms that are white" (*presented in black and white terms*), but rather that you are referring to the concept evoked by the phrase "black and white" (*presented in black-and-white terms*).

Be aware, though, that hyphenation rules are not widely well understood, and it is quite common to see phrases hyphenated or not hyphenated in ways that would not traditionally be considered correct.

Comment: Thank you. So, in example 2, there is no need to hyphenate "black and white" even though it also operates as an adjective?